# How to make Discord bot NOT send message if no one posted

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

The following Discord bot written in Python sends random messages every 6 hours. How can I amend the code so that the bot doesn NOT post again if nobody posted in the channel after the bot?

**Code:**

```
import os
import discord
import asyncio
import random
from messages import messages_list
from copy import deepcopy

key = os.environ['BOT_TOKEN']

client = discord.Client()

async def background_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    messages = deepcopy(messages_list)
    cleanmessages = deepcopy(messages_list)
    while not client.is_closed:
        channel = client.get_channel("Channel_ID")
        if not messages:
            messages = deepcopy(cleanmessages)
        await client.send_message(channel, messages.pop(random.randrange(0, len(messages))))
        await asyncio.sleep(21600)

client.loop.create_task(background_loop())
client.run(key)
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll save the message that we sent, and then use [`client.logs_from`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logs_from) to look at all the messages that come after that message.

```
async def background_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    last_message = None
    messages = deepcopy(messages_list)
    cleanmessages = deepcopy(messages_list)
    channel = client.get_channel("Channel_ID")

    while not client.is_closed:
        if not messages:
            messages = deepcopy(cleanmessages)
        if len([x async for x in client.logs_from(channel, limit=2, after=last_message)]) > 1:
            content = messages.pop(random.randrange(0, len(messages)))
            last_message = await client.send_message(channel, content)
        await asyncio.sleep(21600)
```

Comment: Thank you @Patrick Haugh, but now nothing happens the bot doesn't post at all

Comment: @RompelSt0mpel Oops it's that `last_message and ...`.  Because `last_message` starts at `None`, there's no opportunity for it to post for the first time. Give me a second.

Comment: @RompelSt0mpel It looks like `None` is a valid value for `after`, so removing the `last_message and` should be sufficient.

Comment: seems Python doesn't like the `last_message` line where it is as I get the following error : _last_message = await client.send_message(channel, content)
                                                             ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation_

Comment: @RompelSt0mpel Just delete the indentation in front of that line and reindent it the same way you do the rest of your code.

Comment: Haugh, that worked thank you. But I get the following error: _if any(await client.logs_from(channel, after=last_message)):
TypeError: object LogsFromIterator can't be used in 'await' expression_

Comment: @RompelSt0mpel Try it without the `await` then.

Comment: Nope this is not working at all. The next error I get is: _if any (client.logs_from(channel, after=last_message)):
TypeError: 'LogsFromIterator' object is not iterable_

Comment: Try `any(x async for x in client.logs_from(channel, after=last_message))` if you're on python 3.6 or `recent_messages = yield from client.logs_from(channel, after=last_message); if any(recent_messages)`

Comment: What is the 'x' for?

Comment: So `logs_from` is a coroutine, which is a special form of generator that can be interacted with asynchronously. Unfortunately, coroutines can't be used in ways a normal generator could, like inside something that consumes an iterable (`any` in our case).  `x async for x in client...` is an asynchronous generator expression.  So we're basically making a bridge between the `any` code, which is not asynchronous and the `logs_from` code, which is.

Comment: Oh I see, because now again no error, but also nothing happening, no messages ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @RompelSt0mpel Are there messages already in that channel? You could try `if not last_message or any(...)`

Comment: wait sorry this was my fault, I had incorrect indentation, which I fixed, however I am getting the following error: _any(x async for x in client.logs_from(channel, after=last_message))
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable_

Comment: @RompelSt0mpel try `any([x async for x in client.logs_from(channel, limit=2, after=last_message)])`.  That should throw it into a list, which is iterable.  (It looks like asynchronous generator expressions make asynchronous generators, which is retrospect isn't surprising )

Comment: Well we are making progress and I want to thank you for you patience. The bot is posting yay!! But it is posting just like originally, continuing to post even if a user has not posted in the channel

Comment: @RompelSt0mpel Try printing out that `[x async for ...]` list before the `if` statement. It's possible that we're getting all messages since the last message *including* that message, which we don't want.  If that's the case, we can change the check to `if len([x async for x in client.logs_from(channel, limit=2, after=last_message)]) > 1:`

Comment: _if len([x async for x in client.logs_from(channel, limit=2, after=last_message)]) > 1:_ This did the trick, you are a genius! Thank you very much!